# session as reference .net core

Tags: c#, session, .net-core

I'm new on .net core.
I use session in .net core, but I see that when I use complex object, I must serialize/deserialize the object and then save in session.

That mean that when I load a complex object from session I have to serialize and save that object in session every time at the end of page state.

There is a trick to serialize/save the object only when the object is modified?

(I mean, in the asp.net, the session save/load is automated, there is a similar job in .net core?)

thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about such trick but you can introduce a couple of extension methods to accept typed parameters for cache values setting/retrieval.

One of possible implementation options is to serialize the object to be cached to JSON and then cache the UTF8 representation of it. Using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)'s [`PreserveReferencesHandling.All`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) it's possible to serialize entire object hierarchy with all required dependencies so that you may restore the entire hierarchy on deserialization.

```
public static class TypedSessionValuesExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value,
            new JsonSerializerSettings {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
            });
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        session.Set(key, bytes);
    }

    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this ISession session, string key, out T value)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        if (!session.TryGetValue(key, out bytes))
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
        try
        {
            var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that in case of complex hierarchies and different cached values referencing the same objects this approach may add unnecessary overhead and deserialized object duplication. In this case you may implement `Set<T>()` and `TryGetValue<T>()` extension using serialization method that better suits your object hierarchy.

Comment: Excuse me, thant mean that I have to save everytime all the object at the end of page state?